# Vimeo play buttons doesn't work in my swift app

Tags: swift, vimeo-player

When I press play button it turns blue and nothing happens. However if I press in the center of the screen, video starts playing.

When I test it on simulator, everything is ok, but on my phone it doesn't

[image: ![like that](https://i.ibb.co/8rHD5fM/Screen-Shot-2019-07-02-at-11-22-09-PM.png" alt="Screen-Shot-2019-07-02-at-11-22-09-PM)]

I'm using UIWebView

```
loadHTMLString("<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: black;color: black;}</style><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes\"/></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><div><iframe src=\"\(link)?autoplay=1&amp;?playsinline=0&amp;?title=1&amp;byline=1&amp;portrait=1;autopause=0\" width=\"\(size.width)\" height=\"\(size.height)\" frameborder=\"0\"\"></iframe></div></body></html>")
```

UPDATE:
So, the solution is very simple — use WKWebView instead of UIWebView